# Ubuntu 14.04 Boot Problem

Tags: boot, 14.04, kernel, live-usb

I am currently using windows 7 and wanted to try out Linux. I found out that Ubuntu is the most easy to learn Linux OS. So I create a Live USB of Ubuntu 14.04 with the help of the following link:

[How to make your own "Ubuntu LiveUSB"](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-your-own-Ubuntu-LiveUSB/?ALLSTEPS)

I created the Live USB successfully, but when I started my PC, i encountered an error message saying :

> Kernel Panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Along with a lot of commands which I cannot even understand. I would be very grateful if anyone can tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, all software (including Live USB creators) contains bugs. I assume this is an issue with Pendrivelinux (which I experienced to be very buggy.)

Give [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) a chance. It is the best and safest Live USB creator I ever used, any I tried lots of them...

(And don't be afraid of UNetBootin's boot menu, as some people reported to me...)